# decrypting a file on server, checking its hash and digital signature and then encrypting it again and saving on file server

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography

My application requires the users to upload digitally signed pdf and then encrypt the file. This encrypted file is then uploaded on server, where it is decrypted. The decrypted file is then verified by matching the hash of file and digital signature. Now this file is encrypted with using AES algorithm. Once encryption is completed the file is then stored on file server. The size of file could go upto 80mb.

**The challenge I am facing now is that when the encrypted file is stored on local drive of machine the files get saved instantly but when the file server is on another machine it takes upto 30 min to save a single file. I am not able to figure out the reason for it.**

Following is the code which I am using. I have deployed and tried in tomcat 6 and IBM WAS. The file transfer takes the same time when transferring to file server. The file server is connected to Application server via SAN network.

Following is my encryption code

```
strSymAlg = rb.getString("SYM_KEY_ALG"); //SYM_KEY_ALG=AES

                cipher = Cipher.getInstance(strSymAlg);

                SecKey = new SecretKeySpec(hex2Byte(sSymmetricKey), strSymAlg);

                cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, SecKey);

                baos = recoverFile(new FileInputStream(fileEnv), cipher);

                if (baos != null &&  isRecoveredFileValid((InputStream) new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray()))) {

                    fileRecovered = (InputStream) new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
                }

            }


private ByteArrayOutputStream recoverFile(FileInputStream in, Cipher cipher)  {
        int blockSize = cipher.getBlockSize();
        int outputSize = cipher.getOutputSize(blockSize);
        byte[] inBytes = new byte[blockSize];
        byte[] outBytes = new byte[outputSize];

        int inLength = 0;
        int outLength = 0;
        boolean more = true;

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        try {

            while (more) {
                inLength = in.read(inBytes);
                if (inLength == blockSize) {
                    outLength = cipher.update(inBytes, 0, blockSize, outBytes);
                    baos.write(outBytes, 0, outLength);
                } else {
                    more = false;
                }
            }
            if (inLength > 0) {
                outBytes = cipher.doFinal(inBytes, 0, inLength);
            } else {
                outBytes = cipher.doFinal();
            }
            baos.write(outBytes);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("recoverFile1: " + e.getMessage());
           // e.printStackTrace();
            baos = null;
        }

        return baos;
    }
```

my encryption code is

```
 String strSymKey = "";

        File fileToCreate = null;

        KeyGenerator keygen = KeyGenerator.getInstance(strSymAlg);
        random = new SecureRandom();
        keygen.init(random);
        SecretKey secKey = keygen.generateKey();


        Key publicKey = getPublicKeyFromString(sPubKey.trim());

        //encrypt Symmetric key with public key
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
        cipher.init(Cipher.WRAP_MODE, publicKey);
        byte[] wrappedKey = cipher.wrap(secKey);

        strSymKey = byte2hex(wrappedKey);



        fileToCreate = new File(strFile);
        if (fileToCreate.exists()) {
            fileToCreate.delete();
        }

        //Encrypt Bidder file with symmetric key
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(strFile));
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance(strSymAlg);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secKey);
        crypt(fis, out, cipher);
        fis.close();
        out.close();
    //blnDone=true;

    // System.out.println("STRING SYMMETRIC KEY:"+ strSymKey);

    return strSymKey;




public String byte2hex(byte[] b) {

        // String Buffer can be used instead

        String hs = "";
        String stmp = "";

        for (int n = 0; n < b.length; n++) {
            stmp = (java.lang.Integer.toHexString(b[n] & 0XFF));

            if (stmp.length() == 1) {
                hs = hs + "0" + stmp;
            } else {
                hs = hs + stmp;
            }

            if (n < b.length - 1) {
                hs = hs + "";
            }
        }

        return hs;
    }
```

**New Function added**

```
 public void crypt(InputStream in, OutputStream out, Cipher cipher) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        System.out.println("crypt start time :"+ new Date());
        int blockSize = cipher.getBlockSize();
        int outputSize = cipher.getOutputSize(blockSize);
        byte[] inBytes = new byte[blockSize];
        byte[] outBytes = new byte[outputSize];

        int inLength = 0;
        boolean more = true;
        while (more) {
            inLength = in.read(inBytes);
            if (inLength == blockSize) {
                int outLength = cipher.update(inBytes, 0, blockSize, outBytes);
                out.write(outBytes, 0, outLength);
            } else {
                more = false;
            }
        }
        if (inLength > 0) {
            outBytes = cipher.doFinal(inBytes, 0, inLength);
        } else {
            outBytes = cipher.doFinal();
        }
        System.out.println("crypt end time :"+ new Date());
        out.write(outBytes);
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you profiled the application to see where the time goes?

Comment: Most of the time nearly 95% goes to file transfer when the file is again encrypted

Comment: Your code is much more complex than necessary. Just call `read()` and `update()` with the length you read, and doFinal() at the end, with an empty array. And don't worry about the cipher block sizes, use big buffers, 8k or more. Better still use a CipherInputStream and CipherOutputStream. Why do you need to re-encrypt? Are you changing the key? Or algorithm? And if so why?

Comment: Encryption is the requirement of my application as several files from different users will uploaded and then after some time we need to open all the files related to a task at one go. Yes the keys are changed.
 RSA is used for encryption

Comment: @EJP the original file is encrypted with AES algorithm. After decryption of uploaded file it is encrypted with RSA Algo.

Comment: I asked you why. You haven't answered.

Comment: This code was developed before I joined this project. . My application is currently running on a single server with file server on the same machine. It has been decided by management that we need to have two different servers on different local machines. When I tested the application I figured out this issue. I am trying to analyse this issue. The call has been taken by management. The encryption through RSA is being done to avoid any malpractice. The private key of RSA is encrypted by public key of two users who will decrypt the file using the application.

Comment: I would like share the time taken for re-encryption. I have added snippet of code which I found is the real issue. Sharing the time taken to execute the function when file server is on local and on remote server.

File server and application server on same machine: 12 sec
File server and application server on different machine: 9 min 5 sec

Answer (score 0):

You are making the classic mistake of assuming that every read fills the buffer, and another: that it won't do so at end of stream. Neither is correct.

```
while ((count = in.read(buffer)) >= 0)
{
    out.write(cipher.update(buffer, 0, count));
}
out.write(cipher.doFinal());
```

You don't need a `DataOutputStream` for this.

Comment: I am unable to understand. Could you elaborate a little.

Comment: You must be kidding. I've told you *exactly* what's wrong, and I've provided working code that doesn't exhibit the same problems. At this stage I expect you to *try* it and advise them results.

Comment: I removed the data output steam and modified the my code to include your code but the result is same. It took 9 min to submit the file.